After attempting to install AdGuard Home DNS has completely ceased functioning
An attempted install of AdGuard Home did not work out for some reason I'm not sure of. In any case I uninstalled it and rolled back the other changes I made as part of the install.
Unfortunately, DNS has not started working again.
My AdGuard attempt included running the script as indicated here https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdGuardHome?tab=readme-ov-file#automated-install-linux-and-mac as well as this manual piece here https://adguard-dns.io/kb/adguard-home/faq/#bindinuse which overrides some settings for the resolved daemon.
I reversed those manual changes and yet my machine cannot resolve anything. I've searched all over to figure out what to do here but there's nothing obvious as I barely changed anything. Stopped and restarted systemd-resolved, rebooted, added nameservers to the resolve.conf files. Nothing.
/etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search home


Have you tried a brand new install. That might be the only fix. BTW I can not find anything that out right says this works with Ubuntu or the version of Ubuntu you might be using.

That's always an option but this is my media server and home assistant machine, it will be a pain to redo that.

I figured this out after quite a chase. It turns out that my ISP's router (Bell GigaHub) does not allow you to point the DNS at a local IP address and seems to block absolutely everything coming from that IP if you attempt to do so.
It continues to block that IP even if you switch back to 'Automatically set DNS servers' without manually clearing out 'Set DNS servers manually' section.
So this whole thing is down to my ISP's router being a piece of garbage.
